# Working with protractor events using phantomjs\chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, phantomjs, protractor

The following code works well when i'm running protractor using chrome browser. But when i'm changing browser to phantomjs, looks like he cant click at login button.

```
describe('Authentication capabilities', function() {

  var siteUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/';
  var loginURL = 'http://localhost:5000/views/account/login';

  browser.get("http://localhost:5000/");

  var username = element(by.model('credential.username'));
  var password = element(by.model('credential.password'));
  var loginButton = element(by.xpath('//form[1]/button[@type="submit"]'));
  var error = element(by.xpath('//form[1]/div[1]'));

  it('should redirect to the login page if trying to load protected page while not authenticated', function() {
    browser.get(loginURL);
    loginURL = browser.getCurrentUrl();

    browser.get(siteUrl);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(loginURL);
  });

  it('should warn on missing/malformed credentials', function() {
    username.clear();
    password.clear();

    password.sendKeys('test');
    loginButton.click();
    expect(error.getText()).toMatch('Missing credentials');

    username.sendKeys('example');
    password.clear();
    loginButton.click();
    expect(error.getText()).toMatch('Missing credentials');

    username.clear();
    username.sendKeys("admin");
    password.sendKeys("someinvalidpassword");
    loginButton.click();
    expect(error.getText()).toMatch("Password not valid.");

    username.sendKeys("admin2");
    password.sendKeys("someinvalidpassword");
    loginButton.click();
    expect(error.getText()).toMatch("Incorrect username.");
  });

  it('should accept a valid email address and password', function() {
    username.clear();
    password.clear();

    username.sendKeys('admin');
    password.sendKeys('fubotv');
    loginButton.click();
    expect(element(by.binding('{{user.displayName}}')).getText()).toEqual("Administrator");
  });

  it('should return to the login page after logout', function() {
    element(by.xpath('//li[@class="dropdown user-dropdown"]/a[1]')).click();
    var logoutButton = element(by.xpath('//ul[@class="dropdown-menu"]/li[1]/a'));
    logoutButton.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual(loginURL);
  });
});
```

Config for phantomjs:

```
// myConf.js
exports.config = {

  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:9515',

  capabilities: {

    'browserName': 'phantom',

    'phantomjs.binary.path':'./../../node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',

    'phantomjs.cli.args':['--logfile=PATH', '--loglevel=DEBUG']
  },

  specs: [
    'e2e/**/*Test.js'
  ],

  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    onComplete: null,
    isVerbose: false,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: false
  }
}
```

i'm getting error:
Failures:

```
  1) Authentication capabilities should accept a valid email address and password
   Message:
     Error: No element found using locator: by.binding("{{user.displayName}}")


  2) Authentication capabilities should return to the login page after logout
   Message:
     Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: {"message":"Can't find variable: angular","line":4,"sourceId":140550656205136,"stack":"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular\n    at :4\n    at anonymous (:9)\n    at Na (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():14)\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16\n    at phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16","stackArray":[{"sourceURL":"","line":4},{"function":"anonymous","sourceURL":"","line":9},{"function":"Na","sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":14},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":15},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":15},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16},{"sourceURL":"phantomjs://webpage.evaluate()","line":16}],"name":"ReferenceError"}


Finished in 7.568 seconds
4 tests, 7 assertions, 2 failures
```

witch means it still at the login page, because this element {{user.displayName}} exists only at protected page.
when i'm running at chrome, it works as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using twitter bootstrap on your site? It might be that phantomJS is being sized too small. I had the same issue until I did:

```
onPrepare() {
  browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1600, 800);
}
```

Comment: In your protractor.conf.js file. See https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js for reference.